# AVPlayerViewController in uicollectionviewcell - cancel touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

i am having a `AVPlayerViewController`in and custom uicollectionviewcell

how can i disable the call to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` when touched on the AVPlayer from AVPLayerViewController?

there are a bunch of other elements on the cell, wich should trigger the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

actually on the player controls it works, but once they fade out, another touch on the avplayer triggers the didselect.

having an uibutton in the same cell, cancels the touches correctly.

Comment: Why do you want to disable calling? You can just do nothing when it calls. What happen if it calls didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: i want to be able to use the AVPlayerViewcontroller, like single tap should show player controls instead of triggering "didSelect" from collectionview

Comment: It means, tap on collectionview will do nothing? You can disable interaction cell by cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; Not sure this is what you want

Comment: i basicly want to have userinteraction turned on - and the tap on anywhere else should trigger the didSelect, expect when tapped on AVPlayerViewController

Comment: So, when you touch on a cell, it calls didSelectItemAtIndexPath, and AVPLayerViewController doesn't get the touch. Or both cel and player are called?

Comment: right! cell itself gets the touches no matter if you hit the avplayer or not

Comment: What happen if cell gets the touches? player can't get touches? Or cell is highlighted?

Answer (score 1):

One hacky solution is to override your cell's `hitTest` and cancel the selection when the player view is tapped :

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private weak var videoContainer:UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Settings up the video inside the cell :

        let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        player.play()

        videoContainer.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
        playerViewController.view.pinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let convertedPoint = videoContainer.convert(point, from: self)
        if let hitView = videoContainer.hitTest(convertedPoint, with: event) {
            // The tap is somewhere inside the video view, 
            // disable user interaction on the cell and continue
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            return hitView
        }
        else {
            // Tap is outside the video, 
            // use behavior that will trigger `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
    }
}
```